# RCP - How to use existing command for a button inside a panel?

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a doubt regarding RCP.

**How to use a existing command functionality for a button inside the panel?**

For example, take Edit->Cut functionality. I have a panel, inside that I have a button, for this button I need to use the same Edit->Cut functionality.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. Where is this panel? Is it in an editor?

Comment: nope.. i have created a custom menu... consider like File->CutomNew. If that menu is clicked it will open a dialog.. inside that there will be a button.. if that button is clicked.. it should trigger the cut action..

Comment: To cut what? I don't think 'Edit > Cut' will work if it is called from within a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

In RCP 3 you can do it like this:

```
IServiceLocator serviceLocator = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();

ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) serviceLocator.getService(ICommandService.class);

try  { 
    Command command = commandService.getCommand("de.xx.mycommand");

    command.executeWithChecks(new ExecutionEvent());

} catch (ExecutionException | NotDefinedException |
        NotEnabledException | NotHandledException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In RCP 4 you can use `ICommandService`

This is described here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/Snippets#Execute_Command.2FHandler_manually